# war deployed but opening page says 404

Tags: java, deployment, jboss

I have a project deployed on `JBoss 7.1 AS` and I can see in the logs as

```
13:59:03,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
13:59:04,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named LoginManager in deployment unit deployment "web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginManager!com.myorg.bb.business.LoginManager
    java:app/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginManager!com.myorg.bb.business.LoginManager
    java:module/LoginManager!com.myorg.bb.business.LoginManager
    java:global/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginManager
    java:app/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginManager
    java:module/LoginManager

13:59:04,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named LoginCrudService in deployment unit deployment "web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginCrudService!com.myorg.bb.persistence.LoginCrudService
    java:app/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginCrudService!com.myorg.bb.persistence.LoginCrudService
    java:module/LoginCrudService!com.myorg.bb.persistence.LoginCrudService
    java:global/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginCrudService
    java:app/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LoginCrudService
    java:module/LoginCrudService

13:59:04,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named VariableManager in deployment unit deployment "web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/VariableManager!com.myorg.bb.business.VariableManager
    java:app/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/VariableManager!com.myorg.bb.business.VariableManager
    java:module/VariableManager!com.myorg.bb.business.VariableManager
    java:global/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/VariableManager
    java:app/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/VariableManager
    java:module/VariableManager

13:59:04,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named VariableCrudService in deployment unit deployment "web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/VariableCrudService!com.myorg.bb.persistence.VariableCrudService
    java:app/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/VariableCrudService!com.myorg.bb.persistence.VariableCrudService
    java:module/VariableCrudService!com.myorg.bb.persistence.VariableCrudService
    java:global/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/VariableCrudService
    java:app/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/VariableCrudService
    java:module/VariableCrudService

13:59:04,755 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /web-1.0-SNAPSHOT
13:59:04,767 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
[2013-01-22 01:59:04,783] Artifact web:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
```

When I click the url to open the web context as mentioned `http://localhost:8080/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/`, I get 404 NOT FOUND Error

When I see my war file, whats in there, I see

```
⮀ ⭠ branch± ⮀ jar -tvf ~/IdeaProjects/bb/web/target/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
     0 Tue Jan 22 13:58:54 PST 2013 META-INF/
   298 Tue Jan 22 13:58:52 PST 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Tue Jan 22 12:43:46 PST 2013 WEB-INF/
     0 Tue Jan 22 12:43:46 PST 2013 WEB-INF/classes/
     0 Tue Jan 22 13:58:34 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/
445288 Thu May 17 14:46:22 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
 43581 Thu Dec 13 15:30:40 PST 2012 WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.3.1.jar
  2771 Tue Jan 22 12:44:20 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/business-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
287192 Thu Dec 13 15:30:40 PST 2012 WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.2.2.jar
259600 Wed Jan 02 13:25:26 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.7.jar
575389 Thu May 17 14:52:30 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
313898 Thu May 17 12:46:58 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
1891110 Thu Dec 13 15:29:48 PST 2012 WEB-INF/lib/guava-13.0.1.jar
 81271 Wed Jun 06 16:00:00 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
4317092 Wed Jun 06 16:00:14 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar
476002 Wed Jun 06 16:00:04 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.0.Final.jar
648253 Wed Jun 06 16:00:08 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
 60539 Wed Jun 06 16:00:06 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
 31866 Mon Sep 17 10:12:38 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
489884 Thu Dec 20 15:01:58 PST 2012 WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
252684 Fri Jan 18 14:34:20 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar
366462 Fri Jan 18 14:34:22 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.0.9.jar
 12050 Thu Dec 13 15:30:40 PST 2012 WEB-INF/lib/mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar
 12234 Tue Jan 22 13:58:50 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
376114 Thu Dec 13 15:30:42 PST 2012 WEB-INF/lib/querydsl-core-2.9.0.jar
 95539 Thu Dec 13 15:30:40 PST 2012 WEB-INF/lib/querydsl-jpa-2.9.0.jar
  5050 Tue Jan 22 12:44:22 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 26083 Thu Oct 18 13:40:04 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
  9711 Mon Jul 16 10:31:24 PDT 2012 WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
   403 Tue Jan 22 13:58:52 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
220536 Fri Jan 18 14:34:20 PST 2013 WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
```

When I see Admin Console for JBoss, I see that the project is deployed
[image]

What is that I am missing here and doing incorrectly?

Comment: I'm guessing you have your servlets in business-SNAPSHOT? What request URL's are they mapped to? Have you tried those?

Comment: Are there no HTML or JSP pages at all in your project? It looks like your WAR just contains a META-INF and a WEB-INF, but no actual web pages.

Comment: I don't see any JSP/HTML in the war? What is servlets mapping configuration? Try adding either some pages or some servlets?

Comment: add index.jsp/index.html in your war.